# Different results using python chisquare and using table of Chi-squared values

Tags: python, statistics, chi-squared

I need to get p-value through Chi-square. 
My programm is:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare

c = chisquare([10,4,7,5],ddof=[0,1,2,3])

print(c)
```

The result is:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=3.2307692307692308, pvalue=array([ 0.35739509,  0.19881419,  0.07226674,         nan]))
```

When I try to get p-value using table of Chi-squared values( for example from this site https://www.medcalc.org/manual/chi-square-table.php ), results are different.
In this example using python p-value with degrees of freedom = 1(ddof=0) is  0.35739509 but using table p-value is 0.01.
Could you please explain why results are different?

Answer (score 2):

The function `chisquare` performes the [Chi-squared hypothesis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) but the table is about the [Chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

If you want to work with the distribution you need to use [`scipy.stats.chi2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html). In particular, to replicate values from the table:

```
import scipy as sp

p = 0.1
df = 5

x = sp.stats.chi2.ppf(1-p, df=df)
print(x)  # 9.23635689978
```

And to get the p-value for a given x and degrees of freedom:

```
p = 1 - sp.stats.chi2.cdf([10,4,7,5], df=[0,1,2,3])
print(p)  
# [        nan  0.04550026  0.03019738  0.17179714]
```

Note that the table defines *p* as the integral over the probability density function from x to infinity. The cumulative density function in scipy is the integral from 0 to x. Therefore, `p = 1 - cdf`.

Comment: What exactly I have to do to get p-value?

Comment: @LOGA scipy: you need to pass `x` and `df` to the `cdf` function and take 1 minus the result (see second code example). table: find closest value to x in the row that corresponds to your df and take the p-value from top of column. (I have updated the example to use the values from your question.)

Comment: why it returns four values anyway? with df=1 python returns [ nan ... ... ... ]

Comment: four values in -> four values out. What do you mean with df=1 it returns nan?

Comment: firstly I have to count chisquare of this list [10,4,7,5], then I have to count p-value using chisquare. It will show if the distibution of meaning is different from [6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5] (when p-values are equal for all meanings). I need only one p-value to compare if it more than 0.5 - then this list of numbers has bad distribution, or less - then it has good.